# Can I use nginx to redirect to a most recent file?

Tags: nginx

I was wondering if it is possible to have nginx rewrite a URL to point to the most recent (last naturally sorted) version of a file? Basically, I have a directory full of revisions of a file, like this:

```
/var/files/file-5.6.10.3.txt
/var/files/file-5.6.10.12.txt
/var/files/file-5.6.10.20.txt
/var/files/file-5.6.12.1.txt
...
```

And I would like to rewrite a request for "file.txt" to the most recent version of that file. This is kind of what I want to do:

```
root /var/files;
rewrite file.txt $(ls -v /var/files | tail -1);
```

Or a 302 would be good too!

```
location file.txt {
    return 302 $(ls -v /var/files | tail -1);
}
```

Please also note that symlinking is not an option :( I would like to have this handled by nginx, or some extension to nginx.

Comment: Have you considered Nginx's Lua support for this?

Comment: @ceejayoz I have no idea what that is! I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Bounty comment should read "e.g. file1-\*.txt, file2-\*.txt"

Comment: @ceejayoz if you feel up to posting an answer with some details, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution to this problem eventually turned out to be fcgiwrap. This made sense to me, since I was looking to use a shell command within the nginx configuration.

First, install fcgiwrap:

`apt-get install fcgiwrap`

Write a shell script to perform any kind of logic you need and save it somewhere that nginx can access:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Filename: /var/www/script

echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
echo "Content-Length: $( echo "$REQUEST_URI" | wc -c )"
echo

echo "$REQUEST_URI"
```

Launch an fcgiwrap process:

`fcgiwrap -s unix:/run/myfunsocket`

And finally, configure nginx to serve the request:

```
location /subdir {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/script;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/myfunsocket;
}
```

With this strategy, you can catch any type of request with a location block, and have a shell script determine what the output for that URI should be.

More information/examples of nginx/fcgiwrap can be found in the [NGINX Documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/).